# jQuery UI tab switching not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following piece of code. Whenever, user clicks a button, I need to switch tabs. I see the tab getting switched just for a moment but it immediately switches back to the first tab. Why is that? How do I solve this problem?

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">D</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div class="input">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Data source</legend>
                    Blah blah
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Legend</legend>  
                    <div id="accordion">
                        <h4>Check sequence</h4>
                        <div>                              
                            <button id="submitCheckSequence">Test!</button>    
                        </div>
                        <h4>Random section</h4>
                        <div>                               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>    
            </form>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Blah</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Blah</p>
        </div>    
        <div id="tabs-4">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" readonly>
                Blah
            </textarea>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $("#accordion").accordion();

            $("#submitCheckSequence").click(function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 3);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/x01nkasj/1

Here's a working fiddle. @Odelibalta is correct on the fixes, but the basic snippet to prevent it from trying to POST is as follows.

```
        $("#submitCheckSequence").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", 2);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="input">` does not have a closing tag. In addition, your `button` is inside a form. Thats probably why it is refreshing after you click a button within that form. Give `name` attribute to your form and do `e.preventDefault` on it. If you do not have any other input for that form, I'd take the form out and leave the button there alone. That way works on jsfiddle.